# Can the time varying Intensity of an electric field of a wave be measured?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, particle-detectors

Lets say that we have a detector which we use to measure the intensity. Theoretically, the intensity is a varying function of time (When we calculate the Poynting vector) but often in textbooks they say one have to take the average value because even fast detectors (integration time 10E-10 s) can not resolve the oscillation. That makes sense for me for high frequency but lets say we have a wave with very low frequency, lets say 3-30 Hertz and a very fast detector. Would one be able to measure the time varying intensity of a electromagnetic wave?

Comment: your AM radio measures intensity at the audio rate (up to ~5kHz). In general, detectors, mostly diode rectifiers, for amplitude modulation are intensity detectors.

Comment: The device which measures the EM wave must have at least double the bandwidth.

Comment: @Cerise SSB (single sideband) modulation and its demodulator is not "double bandwidth", it is single sideband....

Comment: If you try to measure a frequency $f_{1}$ the instrument must have a bandwidth of $2f_{1}$ AT LEAST.

Comment: @Cerise if you try to measure a frequency $f_1$ you need a filter with an arbitrarily small but nonzero bandwidth, say, $B>0$ centered around the frequency $f_1$, in the band $f_1-B/2, f_1+B/2]$, followed by an intensity (amplitude) detector. This is your standard AM radio, it has a tunable filter whose bandwidth is $~8kHz$ and is tunable between 530kHz and 1.5MHz in 10kHz steps. You are confusing the modulation bandwidth (DSB or SSB) with the carrier frequency.

Comment: Yet the demodulator sees the modulated signal , not the message signal whose spectrum is centered around the carrier frequency.

Comment: @Cerise Old-fashioned vacuum tube AM radio receivers usually did not contain any circuitry with a bandwidth twice the signal frequency. The input stage was tuned to the signal frequency, with a bandwidth of a few 10's of kHz for a 1 MHz signal. The trick, of course, was that that bandwidth was wider than the signal bandwidth, so there was no issue. Indeed, subsequent tuned circuits reduced the bandwidth before measurement to prevent "adjacent channel interference".

Comment: https://www.attoworld.de/fileadmin/user_upload/tx_attoworld/publications/paper_Science_Y2004_M08_D27_V305_P1267.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Plug an antenna into an oscilloscope. If the antenna has decent efficiency at frequencies your scope can display, you'll see lots of "noise" from superimposed electromagnetic waves from various sources. Detecting EM fields is easy. Separating them is more difficult.